# Netplan wpa_supplicant roaming

Tags: 22.04, netplan, wpa-supplicant

Is there a way to configure roaming for a wifi network defined in netplan (on UB22). Like i used to do before by adding bgscan="[some scan settings]" to the wpa_supplicant.